# RE2 and UTF16 (or UCS-2)

Tags: regex, unicode, utf-16, re2

RE2 is great. **Fast** and deterministic.

However, it supports only UTF8. **My strings are natively UTF16**, and converting back and forth would kill performance.

How difficult would it be to implement native **UTF16** capability in RE2?

How difficult would it be to implement native **UCS-2** capability in RE2? (this should be easier)

*i.e. how many hours would a regular programmer need to do this.*

This has been bothering me for a couple of weeks, so I thought I would ask!

Comment: Is your only real question "how difficult/how long"? That's rather hard to answer and depends a lot on the definition of what you call a "regular programmer". :)

Comment: Yes, I know. How about 'how long would it take you'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Russ Cox, the creator of RE2, was kind enough to post the patch for UCS-2 support. Some assertions, however, are not supported for UCS-2. Reply from Russ is posted verbatim:

> Hi.  RE2 had a UCS-2 mode before I open sourced it, but it could not
>   support assertions like ^, $, and \b, which limited its utility.  If
>   you don't need those operators, then it would probably work for you. 
>   I don't plan to re-add UCS-2 mode to the RE2 sources, but I did just
>   publish the diff for the change that removed it.  You should be able
>   to reverse the diff in a local copy to get the UCS-2 support back. 
>   The file is ucs2.diff in the root of the Mercurial repository.
>
> Enjoy.

Link to code: http://code.google.com/p/re2/source/list

Answer (score 0):

Have you asked Russ Cox what his opinion might be about the answer to your question? I bet it is much too long to contemplate.

I really think you are overvaluing the cost of converting from ugly UTF-16 into normal UTF-8, and undervaluing the cost of recoding a very highly tuned library.

Just bite the bullet and use UTF-8 like th rest of us.

I’m a big RE2 fan myself, but it never occurred to me to want to use it on UTF-16.  UTF-16 is just not part of my world. Just like any other legacy encoding, anything we get in UTF-16 is immediately upgraded to UTF-8 so that the whole toolchain can work with it, because we run a pure-UTF8 toolchain.

Perhaps you live in the opposite world?

Comment: Hi, as a matter of fact I did, and he was kind enough to post the UCS-2 code in the official repo! Yes, part of me lives in the Windows world. See answer.

Comment: Or in Asia. I doubt China has much love for UTF8. And even in the west UTF-16 (or rather USC2) plays quite a role. Java, .NET and SQL Server are techs that use it I know of the top of my head.